# CSS responsive for 1080p and above

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

Recently I am thinking about creating a responsive website that displays really well on high resolution screens, like 2k and 4k screens, I will also make it responsive on desktop and smaller devices.

**Problem:**
Because different screen sizes will have different **font size, padding and margin** so there is going to be a lot of similar media query codes and I don't think it's a good idea to repeating similar media query codes so is there any other good approaches?

Example of REPEATING SIMILAR CODES:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .title{
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .title{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  .title{
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  .title{
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 3840px) {
  .title{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

Is above approach the only approach or is there any other ways I can use so I don't need to change **font size, padding and margin** on every different screen size.

Comment: You could scale off of vw instead and use calc (don't know if that'd be a good idea), or use JS to be less repetitive

Comment: I personally do this in my projects. this is normal practice. the main thing is that every media request is justified by technical necessity.

Answer (score 0):

After some trying out, I created a sass mixin to help myself with my responsive design, I am not sure if this works 100% well but I think it might be able to help a little.

code:

```
@function size-number($base-size, $new-size) {
    @if $new-size != 0 {
        @return $new-size;
    } @else {
        @return $base-size;
    }
}

@mixin break-points-resize ($properties) {
    $PROPERTIES: $properties;
    $BREAKPOINTS: ("1920px","2560px","3840px",);

    @for $i from 1 through length($BREAKPOINTS) {
        @media only screen and (min-width: nth($BREAKPOINTS, $i)) {
            @each $PROPERTY-KEY, $PROPERTY-VALUE in $PROPERTIES {
                $SIZE-NUMBERS: map-get($PROPERTY-VALUE, "size" );
                // [1920px default size => 2], [2560px default size => 3], [3840px default size => 4]
                $BASE-SIZES: (size-number(2,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 1)),size-number(3,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 2)),size-number(4,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 3)));
                $INDIV-PROPERTY-KEY: $PROPERTY-KEY;
                $VALUE-NUMBERS: map-get($PROPERTY-VALUE, "value" );
                #{$INDIV-PROPERTY-KEY}: $VALUE-NUMBERS * nth($BASE-SIZES, $i);
            }
        }
    }
}


h1{

    // Specify size, it will use the size that is specified (Three breakpoints, three size)
    @include break-points-resize(("font-size":("value": 2rem,"size": (2,3,3.5))));

    // Specify 0, it will use the default size (Three breakpoints, three size)
    @include break-points-resize(("font-size":("value": 2rem,"size": (0,0,0))));
}
```

Sorry the code is a little messy